# Will the amount of solute change if the solution evaporates? Will the solvent carry the solute with it if it evaporates?

Tags: solvents

If a solution of dissolved metals in aqua regia is heated in an open container and left to dry overnight, will the dissolved metal ions be carried by the evaporated solution or will it stay in the container?

I was trying to get a solution of dissolved metals in aqua regia for ICP measurement but my sample got dried up so I was wondering if this would affect the ICP measurement.

Comment: Solvent shouldn't carry the solute. Common observations prove that unless a solute is volatile all by itself, it will not evaporate along with the volatile solvent.

Comment: Depending on way of drying and solution behaviour, it may get partially away mechanically. Another issue may be quantitative redissolving of residues.

Comment: My experience was that when heated to drying the solidifying sluge at the bottom of a beaker tended to splatter. You can easily tell if there was splattering by solids splattered on the sides of the beaker. Typically the beakers were covered by a watch glass and the reside on the watch glass was rinsed back into the beaker at the next step.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the elements. If your element of interest were arsenic or mercury losses can be significant. You should not have left them open to dryness without supervision. The second important issue related to drying them again was that nitrates/ chlorides can decompose or hydrolyze easily, and your metal of interest may not dissolve easily again. The analysis should be repeated without heating to dryness in an open vessel.

Comment: Hard to think of a solution of As or Hg. But of course others solids can decompose or even be volatile. So OP should just retain the message that if dryness is not desired then it must be avoided.